# Pricing employee stock options

Tags: option-pricing

ESOs are typically priced using the black-scholes model, but with an additional parameter for for the employee turnover rates . An example  http://www.investopedia.com/university/employee-stock-options-eso/eso3.asp

I assume that employee turnover rate can be modeled as a dividend-like parameter on the original black-scholes equation, which makes calls cheaper. But what about the distribution of stock returns? What if 90% of companies with a market cap of less than $200 million (or some size) lose 90% of their market-cap within a decade, and that the expected return is less than than the broader market? (meaning a few winners and lots and lots of losers) Given the high failure rate of small businesses, employee stock options maybe vastly overvalued

Answer (score 1):

Employee stock options (ESOs) have a couple of disadvantages, but the high volatility of small tech company stocks is NOT one of them. It is actually an advantage, as the higher the volatility of the underlying, the higher the option value.

Disadvantages for ESO holders:

- Withholding fees for early exercise.
- Income tax treatment instead of capital gains.
- Decreased portfolio/income **diversification**.

I will expand on the last one as I think it could be often overlooked. An employee works for a small to mid-sized tech company and holds ESO of the company. If the company goes south, the employee is in danger of not only losing her income stream but also sustaining great losses on the ESOs. The employee's income stream and portfolio value are greatly correlated and unless steps are taken to hedge and diversify, ESOs will represent less value to the individual on a Risk Adjusted basis.